# How to view all of Windows 10 updates?

Tags: windows-update

Rarely have I experienced frustration as severe as this; it may be because I've never had a problem with something this basic even when I was new waaaaay back on XP.

Apparently, when I search for Windows 10 updates, there are only a pitiful few since I reinstalled Windows 10 earlier this month; 4 quality, 19 Driver and 1 listed as "other."

I've spammed windows update and while it seems to pull updates in, it never says that it's installing them and doesn't list any new dates in the list(s).

Checking Windows Defender, I find that its saying that it's also receiving updates *but I can't see **any** of them.*

Looking online, I see a list of updates here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018124/windows-10-update-history that are for **"Windows"** but nothing else specifically. I'm interested in learning what security, or other related Windows updates I've been (or not) getting.

Am I missing something? This is painful for me... Please help...There must be some admin tool I'm overlooking in this newer OS or even a 3rd party tool that I could use to view a complete history.. I mean I once retrieved a product key through a 3rd party tool but I'm coming up empty this time... If I'm experiencing a security issue, then I would like to immediately perform counter-measures.

I'm hoping that nothing is wrong and I'm panicking over nothing.

Comment: install the last one you see on the website for the secific windows 10 build you use, it replaces all older updates.

Comment: There are no download links for it.

Comment: there is a link. I posted an answer with several pictures.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, the updates (except Servicing Stack and Adobe Flash updates) are cumulative, which means, they replaced older ones.

To get the last update, you need to check which windows 10 feature version you use. Run `winver.exe` and look for the version:

[image]

Here I run the windows 10 anniversary update Version 1607. So I have to check the entry **Updates for Windows 10 Version 1607 and Windows Server 2016** [on the Update history page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825)

Here I can see that there are 2 newer updates compared to my.

[image]

The last one is:

[August 28, 2017—KB4039396 (OS Build 14393.1670)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039396)

On this site, there is a link to the Microsoft Update Catalog website:

[image]

Click this link and here you get download links for 32Bit (x86) and 64 Bit (x64) version of the update:

[image]

Click on download and here you see a downloadlink:

[image]

Download the update and double click on the .MSU to install it.

Comment: As I've stated, I've only recently reinstalled Windows 10 and I've received no new updates since mid August (that I can see a history of). Looking up the build, apparently windows 10 is already version 1703.  Does this have anything to do with things already being the most recent? Again, how can I see what other little updates have rolled in? Earlier this year, before I uninstalled, I got updates up the wazoo (please excuse my "French"). How is it I have a history of 0 updates in the last 2 weeks?

Comment: for 1703, [KB4034674 (OS Build 15063.540)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034674/windows-10-update-kb4034674) is the last update. run **winver.exe** and look if you use this version. if yes, everything is fine.